# Attaching a file to an email that sent using django-rest-framework and sendgrid

Tags: django-rest-framework, sendgrid, email-attachments

I'm using Django rest framework to create an api.
I have a POST request that requires a FileField, and I need that the file attached to this request will be sent to some email address.
The only problem I facing is that I can't attach files to this mail without a problem.

Here is the logic that i put inside the POST view:

```
email = EmailMessage('subject', 'some message', 'from@me.com', emails_list)
email.attach_file(MYMODEL.SOME_FILE) # << the problem is here, without it all working
email.send()
```

The error that I've got is: `expected bytes-like object, not FileDescriptor`

the file type is word document `(application/octet-stream)`

what am I doing wrong? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

inside of POST view method:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
```

first, I saved the instance inside DB, and then accessed to its path inside

```
instance = serializer.save()
        email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
            'Subject',
            'Message',
            'from_emails',
            ['to_emails'])
        email.attach_file(instance.FILE_TO_SEND.path)
        email.send()
```